# Remove tfoot (footer column names ) from wp_list_table

Tags: wordpress

Hi I am creating plugin which has many table in different different pages, I am using `wp_list_table` class to create tables. Now I have to remove footer column names form all tables, only at header column names needed.

I can hide it using css:

```
tfoot{
    display:none;
}
```

But I have got task to remove footer using codes only not using css.

I have searched over google and its class reference but I can't get only header column names it both comes from one function.

Still I have not to much deep idea about `wp_list_table` can anyone help me?

Comment: From [codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table): `This class's access is marked as private. That means it is not intended for use by plugin and theme developers as it is subject to change without warning in any future WordPress release. If you would still like to make use of the class, you should make a copy to use and distribute with your own project, or else use it at your own risk.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no filter for this, because this class is marked as private. (like dingo_d already said).

[Look at the code where tfoot will be outputed.](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php#L1144)

> If you would still like to make use of the class, you should make a copy to use and distribute with your own project, or else use it at your own risk.

You can copy the class (it is recommended) and simply delete this lines:

```
<tfoot>
<tr>
    <?php $this->print_column_headers( false ); ?>
</tr>
</tfoot>
```